# How to pass a web worker instance to another component in react js?

Tags: reactjs, web-worker

Is it possible to pass a web worker instance to another component in react js?

If I start a web worker in one component and then I navigate to another component, should I terminate the previous worker and start a new worker? What are the best practices?

How do I listen to post message event of a web worker in two different react components?

Scenario:
There is a search input and a search button. As soon as user starts typing in the input, after 2 sec delay, I start a web worker in the background to get data from a remote server. When results are back, it is shown in the suggestions below the input. But if the user clicks the search button, before the worker has finished, it navigates to second component, then how do I access the worker instance in the second component?

Comment: Assuming your worker is used to retrieve data from a remote server, shouldn't it pass data to your component via some kind of store?

Comment: Yes. But If user navigates to the other component, before the worker has finished its task, the worker will continue running in the background. Then I will need to have a wroker instance in the second component to listen to the on-message event. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a reference to a function which contains the worker functions which child component can make use of. Here's an example of how a parser worker might be setup:

```
const ComponentWithWorker = ()=>{
const workerRef = useRef(); 
useEffect(() => {
    workerRef.current = new Worker(new URL('web-workers/parserWorker.js', import.meta.url));
    () => {
      workerRef.current.terminate();
    };
  }, []);
}
const parserWorker(stuff)=>{
    worker.postMessage({content: stuff})
    worker.onMessage((data)=>{...})
}
return (
    <ParserContext.Provider value={{ parser: parseWorker }}>
        ...
    </ParserContext.Provider>
)
}
```